# Allocation Size for Backup disk on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, configuration, storage

What would be the optimal allocation size for a backup disk for SQL Server? We have a 2014 instance which was using Veeam backups till recently, but we decided to switch to local backups again for some reasons. Does the 64k size hold good for backups as well? Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Backups are written sequentially, and as such they are far less sensitive to allocation unit and sector sizes.

64K should be no problem at all.